# Update table view Error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql-view

When trying to make changes to a PostgreSQL view I get the following errors. Can someone advise how to get this working? I'm not familiar with triggers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to edit a view... views require triggers that update the underlying tables that make up the view... so you have to write rules on how the view will be updated (remembering it is made of several tables via a sql query).

Try the answer to the question I asked on this subject a while back: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211160/9880