# PostGIS Commit Error in QGIS for PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have created the QGIS plugin in version 3.4 and trying to run the same in QGIS 3.10.12. The plugin is just about digitizing rules. I am able to save the data to PostgreSQL in QGIS 3.4 but in QGIS 3.10.12 for saving the data after Plugin execution, I am getting error with the error message stating something like below messages:

```
"['ERROR: 1 attribute value change(s) not applied.', '\n  Provider errors:', '    PostGIS error while changing attributes: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input\n    LINE 1: ...llength"=6,"undegroundroute_id"=NULL,"usedfiber"=NULL WHERE \n^\n    ']"
```

while checking log messages, under PostGIS tab I am getting below message.

```
WARNING    Erroneous query: UPDATE "web_gis"."underground_utility_box" SET "additional_info"=NULL,"authority"=2,"construction_status"=12,"ownership"=1,"condition"=NULL,"installed_date"=NULL,"landmark"=NULL,"make"=NULL,"owner"=NULL,"uub_type"=3,"uub_depth"=1,"uub_length"=1,"uub_width"=1 WHERE returned 7 [ERROR: syntax error at end of input
             LINE 1: ...ub_type"=3,"uub_depth"=1,"uub_length"=1,"uub_width"=1 WHERE
              ^
             ]
```

I am not understanding what is this error message.

The image of error message is attached for reference
[image]

The image for field name and field types attached.
[image]

**Update:** I tried my plugin in Qgis 3.10.5 version and it is working fine without any error whereas in Qgis 3.10.12 the error arises as mentioned above.

Comment: It's better to share a sample of data and table's columns and types. This may help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211160/67659

Comment: @ArashMad, I added image for Field names and Types, also please check the note as Plugin is working fine in Qgis 3.10.5 but not in Qgis 3.10.12.

Comment: Did you try the `UPDATE` query without using quotation mark? `UPDATE _tb
SET _col = 'val'`