# Can not add features to layers created from PostgreSQL's Updateable Views in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql-view

I can not insert on an updateable view with QGIS,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  mytext text,
  geom geometry(point)
);
CREATE VIEW bar AS TABLE foo;
```

When I map `bar` as a layer and try to create a new feature on it, I get,

```
Could not commit changes to layer bar

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, asdf, null).
```

Comment: Are you editing the view in QGIS? That's a whole different subject requiring back-end rules in PostgreSQL and you might want to see this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88120/how-to-set-posgis-default-sequential-value-in-a-qgis-editable-view?s=2|48.4437

Comment: You need to create trigger INSTEAD OF for your view with incrementing gid (https://vibhorkumar.blog/2011/10/28/instead-of-trigger/)

Comment: Even if the INSTEAD OF trigger is created, I do have the same problem too. I have to manualy enter something in the "gid" field. I could also leave it blank and the sequence does its job, but from a user point of view, it might be confusing.

Comment: @DPSSpatial no, that's using the rule system to create a PostgreSQL updateable views. That's still what PostgreSQL does under the hood, but this is with the autogenerated view (9.5+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [QGIS Bug #18586](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18586)

Having researched this and recreated this myself. I've [opened up a bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18586).